# How do I increment part of a variable name in a filtered list?

Tags: excel, vba

First time asking a question here so please bear with me if it's not correct.

I am currently creating an asset tracking system, and am trying to automate how items are added and given an asset ID.

Currently, the format is as follows:

**Name**-**Asset Type**-**number** (*example: Bloggs-LAPTOP-0002*)

I've already used VBA to be able to automatically fill in the "Name" and "Asset type" in the ID, however, due to the fact there can be two assets with the same number (LAPTOP-0003 and MONITOR-0003) I am struggling to find a way to filter the data on what assets we have already, sort them into order, then find what value would next be in the list to add to the name.

To be clear, I'm looking for a method to filter the data into asset types, such as all laptops, sort them so they are in ascending order, then find the last value, add 1 to the numerical value at the end of the ID and save that as the new asset ID.

Any help on this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you already narrowed it down to name and asset, just count via loop then +1?

Comment: Loop over all the rows, split each id on "-", check the second element in the array to see if it's the type you need, then if Yes check the last element to find the largest value.  Add one to that for the new id.  Or keep a table of current values for each type.

Comment: Hi! I am able to filter the data to show me all the "LAPTOPS" but I have no idea how to split up the asset ID to get the number, sort by the number then add 1, I am attempting to do this all in a macro, with the end goal being that when a user adds a new asset it auto-fills the Asset ID column, and whilst I can filter by Asset type (e.g LAPTOPS) it then applies that to the sheet which was not the outcome I had wanted

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with formulas:

If your existing Asset IDs are in column D, you could create a new column (column E) and drag down this formula from cell E1:

```
=LEFT(D1, SEARCH("-", D1, SEARCH("-",D1) + 1))
```

which extracts Name and Type. Then, if your new Name is in cell A1 and new Type is in cell B1, you could calculate the new ID number with this formula:

```
=COUNTIF($E:$E,A1&"-"&B1&"-") + 1
```